# Searching chars in database records?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have variable

```
Dim s As String = "1,5,20,22,28,31,40"
```

And I have records in (fieldnum) database (mssql) :

```
3,5,19,20,26,28,33,40
1,2,5,18,20,22,31,38
1,7,12,22,23,24,31
```

Now, how to find (SELECT ...???) records where at least 4 numbers in fieldnum are equal with numbers s variable?

In this example must be selected only those two rows.

```
3,5,19,20,26,28,33,40 (equal numbers: 5,20,28,40 = 4 nums)
1,2,5,18,20,22,31,38 (euqal numbers: 1,5,20,22,31 = 5 nums)
```

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server to store and compare JSON strings?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Um, that's not Json. But yeah, why would you do this? This is not the kind of thing SQL was designed for.

Comment: Extract all `fieldnum` values into some .NET construct and find all that match s based on your custom implemented match operator

Comment: @p.s.w.g whatever, everyone knows exactly what I meant.

Comment: if you want to evaluate data elements individually, store them individually.  if the number have a relationship to one another, use relationships in the data model to represent them - NOT the data store to avoid this very thing

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to recognize them as seperate numbers. You could trying using a LIKE search in your sql statement though.